# True ENV Values in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

So in Laravel Mix it says in the docs we can add stuff to our .env file prefixed with MIX_ and we can then access it in our JS file when compiled.

I think I may be missing something here though because this doesn't really offer anything along the lines of an env file as the assets are compiled into production mode locally before you push them up to your server. That means the npm run watch and npm run build will both pick up the same env values right?

It works as a kind of global variable thing but not as an environment variable as you can't set the value depending on what the environment is,

This seems kind of obvious so I assume I missing something ??

Comment: The `npm run build` task may have overrides built-in that tell it what environment to use. It's also very common for this sort of thing to run on a CI server, which would put the appropriate env vars in place.

Comment: So, what is your question about? You are right. After deployment all the env variables will be overwritten with production values.And whatever you have compiled into mix-s would stay the way it was set in dev. It seems to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 10):

@Ohgodwhy's answer works, but need slight modification for new mix version

```
require('dotenv').config()
let webpack = require('webpack')

let dotenvplugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        APP_NAME: JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_NAME || 'Default app name'),
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }
})

mix.webpackConfig({
    ...
    plugins: [
        dotenvplugin,
    ]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this:

Setup steps:

1. `npm install dotenv --save`
2. Add `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of your `webpack.mix.js` file
3. add `let webpack = require('webpack')` after #2

Now you can inject these into your build by using the `DefinePlugin` in your `mix` declaration:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  //...
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      APP_NAME: JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_NAME || 'Default app name'),
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }
  })
})
```

Now your `bundled` files can use `process.env.APP_NAME`, for instance, in the application. This safe guards you from exposing your `.env` file to the browser but allows you to easily share global, insecure values through the full stack.

*Notes*

Note that the `process.env` does not get replaced with the `.env` from Laravel, but rather it exposes it through a merge. Therefore if you are passing, for instance, arguments to `npm/yarn run dev` (such as `NODE_ENV=development`), then you do not need to declare `NODE_ENV` in your .env file. If you do, the `.env` file will take presedence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the bit I don't get is how to tell webpack to use different env files when you do npm run watch and npm run build. This way it always just uses the value from the .env which will always be local

Comment: @ChrisBell require a different `.env` file in your `webpack` file depending on your `NODE_ENV` variable.

Comment: yeah having .env files for php stuff and .env.json files for the node environment stuff seems to be the cleanest way to do this, no sure how to do that in laravel mix tho will need to checkout the docs

Comment: @ChrisBell You would do `if( mix.inProduction()) { } else { }` and require the file depending on whether or not you're in production. You pass `NODE_ENV` in your `scripts:` declaration in your `package.json`, so that should help you resolve the chain of logic.

Comment: This didn't or no longer works (when I tried it) as Mix runs its own plugin (MixDefinitionsPlugin) - that results in a new DefinePlugin instance - after whatever you define, overwriting it with only the MIX_ variables. Spent some time on this trying to come up with an alternative for the multiple-environment thing. Documented it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940016/50158

Answer (score -1):

Here is the way I ended up doing this:

Anyone landing here from google here is how I did this:

env.js

```
let globalEnv = {
  development: {
    embedScriptUrl: 'http://localjspath.js',
    embedCssUrl: 'http://localcsspath.css',
  },
 production: {
    embedScriptUrl: 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pathtojs.js',
    embedCssUrl: 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pathtocss.css',
  }
};

export default function env(property){
  return globalEnv[process.env.NODE_ENV][property];
};
```

You then just import and call env('embedScriptUrl') in your front end JS like you would in a laravel PHP file